# Solve module not found in jupyter notebook with binder

Tags: python, github, jupyter-notebook, yaml, mybinder

I have set up a jupyter notebook within a virtual environment.
Now I want to deploy it with [mybinder](https://mybinder.org/)

I generated an environment.yml directly from the anaconda prompt.

```
name: test_environment
channels:
- conda-forge
dependencies:
  - python
  - numpy
```

The building with binder does not show any errors and the jupyter notebook is launched, but when I try to import the numpy module the notebook tells me that the module has not been found.

When I check on which environment the notebook is running with

```
!conda info
```

I see that it is running on the notebook environment and not on my test_environment.
Yet I have no idea on how to guide binder to my specified environment as it is already in the same directory as my notebook.ipynb file

**Note:** I need my files to stay within a subdirectory of my repository.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and apparently, it has to do with how Binder searches for the `environment.yml` file as you suggested. In my case, **the problem was solved** by simply **creating a new cleaner repo** in GitHub with a more simple structure than the initial one I had. More specifically, the new repo has the following structure in the root directory (i.e. https://github.com/user_name/repo_name/):

```
- README.md
- analysis.ipynb
- environment.yml
```

Comment: Yes that works for me as well. I just can not get binder to find my environment.yml in subdirectories of a repository - and sadly that is my use-case and I can not move out to a new repo. (+1). Any ideas on how to solve that?

Comment: I am glad it worked!
As to the second question, I understand Binder is flexible enough to launch each Jupyter Notebook with its own yml configuration file. See an example here:
https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/tip-speed-up-binder-launches-by-pulling-github-content-in-a-binder-link-with-nbgitpuller/922

Comment: Another thing to keep in mind related to directing binder to the appropriate `environment.yml `, is that you can put `environment.yml` in a specially named sub-directory called `binder` (or `.binder`) and this will be used by mybinder preferentially to build the image from the repo., see ['Can I put my configuration files outside the root of my repository?'](https://mybinder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/about/about.html?highlight=root#can-i-put-my-configuration-files-outside-the-root-of-my-repository). "Binder.. will ignore those [configuration files] in the repository’s root."